# How do I sort an array into subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please help with the task.
There is an array of objects:

```
[
  {id: 0, title: 'title_1', step: 3},
  {id: 1, title: 'title_2', step: 2},
  {id: 2, title: 'title_3', step: 3},
  {id: 3, title: 'title_4', step: 1},
  {id: 4, title: 'title_5', step: 2},
  ...
]
```

How can I turn this array into this one?

```
[
  [
    {id: 0, title: 'title_1', step: 3},
    {id: 2, title: 'title_3', step: 3},
  ],
  [
    {id: 3, title: 'title_4', step: 1},
  ],
  [
    {id: 1, title: 'title_2', step: 2},
    {id: 4, title: 'title_5', step: 2},
  ],
  ...
]
```

That is, split it into subarrays of objects, using the step property

thanks

Comment: is step always a number smaller then the maximum an index could be?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce()` method to get the sub arrays by the step property. Traverse the array using reduce method and make step as a key as well as create sub array based on that key(step). At last, get all the values using `Object.values()` method.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 0, title: 'title_1', step: 3 },
  { id: 1, title: 'title_2', step: 2 },
  { id: 2, title: 'title_3', step: 3 },
  { id: 3, title: 'title_4', step: 1 },
  { id: 4, title: 'title_5', step: 2 },
];

const ret = Object.values(
  data.reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    const key = c.step;
    p[key] = p[key] ?? [];
    p[key].push(c);
    return p;
  }, {})
);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

This version is algorithmically similar to the one from mr hr.  It's just written in the mutation-free style I prefer.  It is less performant, but to my mind easier to understand.  But YMMV.

```js
const groupArrayBy = (prop) => (arr) =>
  Object .values (
    arr .reduce ((a, x) => ({...a, [x [prop]]: [... (a [x [prop]] || []), x]}), {})
  )

const input = [{id: 0, title: 'title_1', step: 3}, {id: 1, title: 'title_2', step: 2}, {id: 2, title: 'title_3', step: 3}, {id: 3, title: 'title_4', step: 1}, {id: 4, title: 'title_5', step: 2}]


console .log (groupArrayBy ('step') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We write a generic function `groupArrayBy` that takes a property name and returns a function that groups an array into subarrays sharing particular values for that property.

You can use it directly as we do above, or you can write a function that partially applies the first parameter, such as

```js
const byStep = groupArrayBy ('step')
// ... later
const results = byStep (input)
```